# Why can't I insert a keyframe into the prop from the operator panel?

Tags: python, operator, panel

In this code example, I try to call an operator popup, in which I put a "location" property of the active object, I'd like to right-click to insert or remove keyframes from these properties, but that doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it's a bug, or my problem, It would be really interesting to understand why, and possibly, how I can fix this?

```
import bpy

class MYPANEL_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "MYPANEL_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout 
        layout.operator("mypanelop.test", text = "Test")

class MYPANELOP_OT_Test(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ """
    bl_idname = "mypanelop.test"
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}
    
    def execute(self,context):
        return{'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self,width=300)
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ob = context.object
        if ob:
            layout.prop(ob,'location')
    

classes = (MYPANEL_PT_Panel, MYPANELOP_OT_Test)
    
def register():
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `layout.prop` that you're using is not in a **Panel**, but in the **Operator dialog**, which serves as an UI to an operation itself, and skips UI events that call for other operators (like the bound key to call 'anim.keyframe_insert', or to invoke another dialog for 'buttons.context_menu' that you mention)..

So if the function of the operator is to also insert a keyframe, you need to do that in the execution call.

```
import bpy

class MYPANEL_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "MYPANEL_PT_Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Test"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout 
        layout.operator("mypanelop.test", text = "Test")

class MYPANELOP_OT_Test(bpy.types.Operator):
    """ """
    bl_idname = "mypanelop.test"
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}
    
    def execute(self,context):
        # INSERTING KEYFRAME 
        context.object.keyframe_insert(data_path='location')
        return{'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self,width=300)
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ob = context.object
        if ob:
            layout.prop(ob,'location')
    

classes = (MYPANEL_PT_Panel, MYPANELOP_OT_Test)
    
def register():
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```